# Test Unit Controller Rest Pageable

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-boot-test

I am trying to perform a unit test on a call from my Controller but I get a **NullPointerException**. The callback returns a `ResponseEntity <Page>` object as exemplified below:

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<Page<CentroDeCusto>> centrosDeCustos(Pageable paginacao) {
    Page<CentroDeCusto> centrosDeCustos = centroDeCustoRepository.departamentosPorDataDeAtualizacao(paginacao);

    if (centrosDeCustos.hasContent())
        return new ResponseEntity<>(centrosDeCustos, HttpStatus.OK);
    else
        return new ResponseEntity<>(centrosDeCustos, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

This is my controller test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class CentroDeCustoRestControllerTeste {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mvc;

@MockBean
private CentroDeCustoRepository repository;

@Test
@WithMockUser(username = "teste-app-@teste.com", authorities = {"ADMIN"})
public void aoBuscarCentrosDeCustoRetornarUmaListaComVariosCentrosDeCusto() throws Exception {
    PageRequest paginacao = PageRequest.of(1, 10);
    List<CentroDeCusto> centrosDeCustos = Arrays.asList(new CentroDeCusto(), new CentroDeCusto());
    Page<CentroDeCusto> centrosDeCustosPage = new PageImpl<>(centrosDeCustos, paginacao, centrosDeCustos.size());

    given(repository.departamentosPorDataDeAtualizacao(paginacao)).willReturn(centrosDeCustosPage);

    mvc.perform(get("/centrosdecustos").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

**The error occurs in this Controller call: if (centrosDeCustos.hasContent())**

Follow the error details:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:71)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:165)
at br.com.tete.unidade.centrodecusto.CentroDeCustoRestControllerTeste.aoBuscarCentrosDeCustoRetornarUmaListaComVariosCentrosDeCusto(CentroDeCustoRestControllerTeste.java:72)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at br.com.tete.centrocusto.CentroDeCustoController.centrosDeCustos(CentroDeCustoController.java:31)
at br.com.tete.centrocusto.CentroDeCustoController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d47fb791.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:69)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
at br.com.tete.centrocusto.CentroDeCustoController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$398ebec1.centrosDeCustos(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
... 83 more
```

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that you aren't hydrating your controller's Pageable object correctly. So then what's happening is that your mock when(..) isn't being triggered because it doesn't qualify with what is actually being passed into your repository method. Spring is using the default of page=0, size=20 if you don't actually pass anything different.

You can solve this in two ways:

Actually call it as you would so Spring can create the Pageable with what your "paginacao" actually looks like..

```
mvc.perform(get("/centrosdecustos?page=1&size=10").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

or

Just use a Mockito.any to trigger on any PageRequest.

```
given(repository.departamentosPorDataDeAtualizacao(Mockito.any(PageRequest.class))).willReturn(centrosDeCustosPage);
```

Comment: Thank you Hermann Steidel. It worked! Please, could you also help me with the doubt in this other post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54619839/test-unit-spring-boot-unable-to-register-mock-bean?noredirect=1#comment96048786_54619839 I followed the suggestions but the same error continues. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure. No problem, I can take a look. Accepting my answer would be appreciated.